# Google custom search engine android not accepting %20 or white space

Tags: java, android, google-custom-search

**EDIT 2**

Found my error i was passing invalid an invalid parameter just remebered i was tryiong out stuff.

**Sorry For the Trouble GUYS**

I am using Google custom search engine for the first time and so far every thing is fine. However, when i try to send a query for an item which has a white space the search engine returns a bad request response eg

```
    myUrl = (CustomSearchEngineURL + API_KEY + "&cx=" + cxKey + "&q="
            + q.replace(" ", "%20") + "&searchType=" + searchType
            + "&imgType=" + imgType + "&imgSize=" + imgSize + "&num=20&alt=json");
```

This returns this

```
 com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
```

**EDIT**

i took the advice of 323go and tried encoding my q and this is how i implemented it

```
String encodedParms = null;
    try {
        encodedParms = URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    myUrl = (CustomSearchEngineURL + API_KEY + "&cx=" + cxKey + "&q="
            + encodedParms + "&searchType=" + searchType + "&imgType="
            + imgType + "&imgSize=" + imgSize + "&num=20&alt=json");

    Log.d(Tag, myUrl);

    HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

    HttpRequest request;
    try {
        request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(myUrl));
        String response = streamToString(request.execute().getContent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my log i got this as the url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-w&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=Sunway+Lagoon+Theme+Park&searchType=image&imgType=photo&imgSize=xxlarge&num=20&alt=json
```

i still got the same bad request error

please can anyone tell me what i am doing worng

Comment: Show us how you invoke the url. But generally, you should use `UrlEncoder` instead of `String.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add "+" between words, I had same issue
With "word1 word2" - response 400 - Bad request
With "word1+word2" - response 2000 - Bad request